is there a way to enable plus addressing in outlook 2021
I have MS Office Pro 2021. I use the IMAP protocol for email.
The 2021 version of outlook is not creating the +addressing email folders automatically.
i.e
myname+gas@domain.com
myname+electricity@domain.com

On my mobile, I have tried two different email apps, and both of them show the folders being created, so they are there - but Outlook does not show them.
is there a way to get outlook 2021 to show these folders?
which outlook version will be capable after 2021? i dont really want subscription version (office 365), so if office 2024 does it, i may upgrade to that
